# DataContext resolution issues in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I created a class `PagedView` which inherits from `ContentControl`.
Further I defined a `ControlTemplate` for `Foo` inside a `ResourceDictionary`.

The `ControlTemplate` starts like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:PagedView">
    <Grid Background="White" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:PagedView}}}">
```

(I chose this way of defining this control because I needed to supported named content and it's the only way so far that worked)

Now I can just use `PagedView` somewhere and set it's content to my needs, e.g.:

```
<controls:PagedView>
    <TextBlock Text="FooBar" />
</controls:PagedView>
```

Then I added another `DependencyProperty "Header"` to `PagedView` in order for me to add additional content to some part of the control.

Inside the style of `PagedView` I added the following line to support this additional content:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}" />
```

I'm now able to add additional controls like this:

```
<controls:PagedView.Header>
    <CheckBox Content="FooCheck" />
</controls:PagedView.Header>
```

Now I wanted to bind the `IsChecked` property to another dependency property  defined in the `Page` using `PagedView` but unfortunately it seems that the `Binding` cannot be resolved correctly as the dependency property bound to doesn't change whenever I toggle the `IsChecked` state of the `CheckBox`.

I'm not really fluent in the rules on how WPF determines the correct `DataContext` for each element in the UI, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you set the top level Grid's DataContext on the PagedView Template to the PagedView itself? The DataContext of a control should usually be inherited from its parent element and hold a reference to a view model object.

Comment: You could instead have `Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:PagedView}}"` or `Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"` (if its in the ControlTemplate).